# What is the difference between these two jQuery usage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, logic, concept

Im a jquery starter so if its a wrong one forgive me :)

I just want to know why placing the content at different positions made this script working, although to my best i think script to kept in `head` section of the document. Please explain the concept.

**Working Code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Example 2</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

<p>
</p>

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery("p").html("Check if jQuery Supports Ajax method : "+ jQuery.support.ajax );
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

**Not Working**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Example 2</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery("p").html("Check if jQuery Supports Ajax method : "+ jQuery.support.ajax );
</script>
</head>

<body>

<p>
</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Read This: http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: @YouQi thx for the link ..jquery seems very vast :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the second instance the code is executed before the `<p>` has been parsed into the DOM tree, so while it still works there's nowhere to put the output text into. In other words, `jQuery("p")` matches no element so `.html()` "does nothing".

You can fix this by either waiting for the DOM to be fully parsed:

```
jQuery(function() {
    jQuery("p").html(...);
});
```

or by using an output mechanism that does not depend on the `<p>` existing, such as `alert()` or `console.log()`.

Answer (score 3):

Well, it seems that your browser firstly load `<head>` section thus in second example there is no `p` element then.

In both cases you should wrap your code in `$(function(){ ... })`.

Answer (score 1):

If you place your script before the `<body>` element, it is executed before the DOM tree is loaded/parsed. The `<p>` element does therefore not exist and cannot be found. You can:

- Place the script after the `<body>` tag (like in your first example)
- or you can call your function after the `ready` event has been fired:

  ```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("p").html("Check if jQuery Supports Ajax method : "+ jQuery.support.ajax );
  });
  ```